# Configuring wp_mail function for IIS Server

Tags: wordpress, iis, smtp

I tried configuring the settings of the IIS Manager and still, it won't work, I have checked the php.ini file of IIS and still no luck.

I also have tried using the WP-Mail-SMTP plugin, still, no luck was found and an error shows up, it looks like this.

```
"The following From address failed: wordpress@test2 : MAIL FROM command failed,550,The address is not valid."
```

Where in test2 is the name of the Server.

I am deploying Wordpress at an IIS / Windows Server.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a gmail account then set your smtp settings.

these a few steps have to be follow:

```
Mailer: SMTP
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port: 465
Encryption: SSL
Authentication: Yes
Username: your full gmail address
Password: your mail password
```